# Postdoctoral Research Fellowship Application Criteria - Functional Responsibility?

Tags: application, postdocs

I'm applying for a position as a postdoctoral research fellow (in mathematics if it matters) and encountered this under the key selection criteria:

"Ability to solve problems by using innovation and the exercise of high level diagnostic skills within areas of functional responsibility or professional expertise"

Googling "functional responsibility" didn't help me understand what is meant by this in an academic context. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is being asked for here?

Comment: Could it not just mean that you should be able to solve the problems that you're _responsible_ for solving as part of your job (i.e., your _function_ in the institution), using innovation and the exercise of high level diagnostic skills?

Answer (score 1):

It's just boilerplate language, not specific to the post-doc position (or even to academic positions, probably).  All "areas of functional responsibility" means is that it refers to the kinds of things that you will be responsible for doing as part of the job.